# How to change geojson style by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Hello based on this leaflet tutorial http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html I am trying to create 20 buttons so that I can change line : 
fillColor:getColor(feature.properties.density) to sth different (for example by pressing         btn #1 fillColor:getColor(feature.properties.btn1), 
btn #2 fillColor:getColor(feature.properties.btn1), etc

```
function style(feature) {
return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
};
}

L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style}).addTo(map);
```

All I want is when a button is pressed, a different geojson property to be displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines

First, turn your layer into a variable

```
var mylayer = L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style});
map.addLayer(mylayer);
```

Create a new function for getting the new style based on your buttons id

```
function newStyle(id) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(id),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
```

Then listen for the click and get the btn id and set the new style

```
$('body').on('click', 'btn', function (btn) {
    var id = $(btn).attr('id');
    var new_style = newStyle(id);
    mylayer.setStyle(new_style);
});
```

UPDATE:

Updated the getcolor to only be getColor(id). You should make your buttons correspond to the colors in the getColor function on the example. So id="11" will return #FED976 from the example, id="21" will return #FEB24C and so on.

Alternatively you could just set your button ids to the color (id="#FED976") and then change the fillColor: getColor(id) to fillColor: id

UPDATE2:

```
function style1(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.btn1)
    };
}

function style2(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.btn2)
    };
}

var mylayer = L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style});
map.addLayer(mylayer);

$('body').on('click', 'btn', function (btn) {
    var id = $(btn).attr('id');
    switch (id) {
        case "btn1":
            map.removeLayer(mylayer);
            mylayer = L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style1});
            map.addLayer(mylayer);
            break;
        case "btn2":
            map.removeLayer(mylayer);
            mylayer = L.geoJson(statesData, {style: style2});
            map.addLayer(mylayer);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I did all that you've written but I ama facing the following error Uncaught ReferenceError: feature is not defined

Comment: See updated version. I recommend the alternative for simplicity. Then you can just set up each button to be whatever color you want.

Comment: The thing is I need fillColor:getColor(feature.properties.btn1) because I want the onclick event not to change the color of the layer but to change the attribute from where it gets the values to be passed to getcolor function

    function getColor(d) {
    return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}

Comment: Sorry, you totally confused me now :) Can you explain exactly what you want to do. When you click one of the buttons you want it to do what exactly??? The getColor function is just using properties off the feature to figure out what color each state should be using fillColor. It does not set anything on the feature properties. If I understand you correctly, what you actually want to do is change the geojson itself then redraw the map so that the states get different colors when you click a button???

Comment: Sorry for your confusion but english isn't my maternal language and maybe I can't really express my thoughts. I want to add a series of buttons that allow the user to adjust the coloring of the map based on the series they are interested in. Based on which of the buttons that pushes, the coloring of the map regenerates by pointing towards a different data attribute in my GEOJSON. I don't want the users to change the color palette, I want them to choose the data attribute.Thanks again for your time.

Comment: OK, I think I get what you mean now. The style function is used when you set the layer so I think the only way you will achieve this is to remove the layer when the button is clicked with map.removeLayer(myLayer) and then add a new layer with the new style function.